# Long datatype throwing numberformatexception

Tags: java

A datatype long in Java 7 is throwing numberformatexception when it is exceeding 20 digits. Is there any alternative here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)s to do mathematical operations with higher number of digits.

But in division, it is doing integer division.(As in integer data types). For large decimal number calculations, you can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

An Example using `BigInteger` is shown below..

```
    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("100000");

    System.out.println("Addition: " + b1.add(b2));
    System.out.println("Subtraction: " + b1.subtract(b2));
    System.out.println("Division: " + b1.divide(b2));
    System.out.println("Multiplication: " + b1.multiply(b2));
    System.out.println("Power: " + b1.pow(1000));
```

For more information you can just google `how to use biginteger in java`